# What does this Azure deployment error mean?

Tags: visual-studio, azure, publish, diagnostics

I'm getting the following error when I try to deploy to my Azure Cloud Service through Visual Studio 2012:

```
Windows Azure could not find the resource Diagnostics in the service package. To 
upgrade the deployment, you must add the resource. Otherwise, perform a new deployment.
```

Any ideas what this means, or how I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did to solve this was to go into my Cloud services on the Azure portal, click the trash can at the bottom, and selected "Delete the production deployment for MyWebSite".  I re-uploaded from Visual Studio, and it worked.

Answer (score 5):

Publish your cloud service once with temporary unchecked "Deployment update" checkbox in Azure Publish Advanced Settings.

Answer (score 0):

When publishing to a new service, it is fine, because the deployment does not have to compare what is already there (it is a new service, so nothing is there) and what is in your package. But while upgrading a service, bunch of settings have to match between an existing service and the package you are trying to upload. So the error you got wasn't about you having something extra in your package, but having something extra in your existing service and missing in the package you were uploading. Hope that helps.

To resolve the issue I have deleted my deployment(production deployment) and again uploaded it.